# How can I center subtitle text in quarto?

Tags: r, quarto

I would like to center one of my sub-headers not the text below it.  I tried the code below and it centers the subheading and also the text in the subsection.

```
---
title: "how do I center only a title"
format: html
---
### Something

something not centered

### A Centered Subheading {style="text-align: center;"}

Blah blah

- Blah
- More blah
- still more blah

### Somethingelse

not centered
```

What is the proper way to center just the subtitle?

Comment: Applying custom CSS?

Comment: Hello @shafee Sadly, I don't know enough CSS to do it.  I tried ### [A Centered Subheading]{style="text-align: center;"} and nothing was centered.  The code above centers the entire section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can center a specific header using `css`. Simply define a class name for that header like here I have used `.test` as a class applied to that header. And then in a separate css file `styles.css`, we need to write the style rules.

```
---
title: "how do I center only a title"
format: html
css: styles.css
---

### Something

something not centered


### A Centered Subheading {.test}


Blah blah

- Blah
- More blah
- still more blah

### Somethingelse

not centered
```

And In the `styles.css` file

```
.test h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**Output**

[image: quarto_doc_with_a_header_centered]

Comment: Thank you so much.  That makes perfect sense now that I see it.  If you make it to Miami, lunch is on me.